# Set as Contact Ringtone? Android

Tags: android, contacts, ringtone

I am trying to learn how to add set as contact ringtone feature. I already know how to set default ringtone but I can't figure how to set as contact ringtone.
I got to the part where I choose contact, but I don't know how to assign ringtone to that contact.
That part is bugging me and I can't seem to find answer in questions that were already asked on this topic.
Here is my code so far:

```
static public final int CONTACT_CHOOSER_ACTIVITY_CODE = 73729;
private File csound;
private final File rpath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Ringtone sounds/Ringtones");


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContRing();

    }

    private void setContRing() {
        Boolean success = false;
        csound = new File(rpath, FNAME);rpath.mkdirs();
        if (!csound.exists()) {




            try {
                InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(FPATH);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(csound.getPath());
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;

                try {
                    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buff, 0, read);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();

                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                success = false;

            }
        } else {
            success = true;
            setContRingtone();

        }

        if (!success) { 
           setContRingtone();


        }
    }

    private void setContRingtone() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_CHOOSER_ACTIVITY_CODE);

    }




});


}
```

Edit for bounty: I am wondering if someone can show me how to do so, I tried with codes found in other questions but I couldn't apply them to my code. I can copy file but how to get contact and assign ringtone to that contact?

Comment: You may find these helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437922/how-can-i-set-a-ringtone-for-an-individual-contact-on-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230444/setting-contact-custom-ringtone-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [set custom ringtone to specific contact number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404214/android-set-custom-ringtone-to-specific-contact-number)

Android has a special column for this: `ContactsContract.CUSTOM_RINGTONE`.

So, you could use `ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri` to get your contact's `Uri`, after that pretty much all that's left is to call `ContentResolver.update`.

Here's an example of looking up a contact by their phone number, then applying a custom ringtone:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;

// The Uri used to look up a contact by phone number
final Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, "012-345-6789");
// The columns used for `Contacts.getLookupUri`
final String[] projection = new String[] {
    Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
};
// Build your Cursor
final Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, projection, null, null, null);
data.moveToFirst();
try {
    // Get the contact lookup Uri
    final long contactId = data.getLong(0);
    final String lookupKey = data.getString(1);
    final Uri contactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
    if (contactUri == null) {
        // Invalid arguments
        return;
    }

    // Get the path of ringtone you'd like to use
    final String storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    final File file = new File(storage + "/AudioRecorder", "hello.mp4");
    final String value = Uri.fromFile(file).toString();

    // Apply the custom ringtone
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
    values.put(Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, value);
    getContentResolver().update(contactUri, values, null, null);
} finally {
    // Don't forget to close your Cursor
    data.close();
}
```

Also, you'll need to add both permissions to read and write contacts:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

To extend a bit on this, and how to modify it to your need, change phone number `012-345-6789` in this line to the one you are looking for

```
// The Uri used to look up a contact by phone number
final Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, "012-345-6789");
```

And set your default CUSTOM_RINGTONE in your phone ContactsContract. There is another, similar, option here:
[Setting contact custom ringtone, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230444/setting-contact-custom-ringtone-how)

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is applying that to my existing code.

Comment: @Sabroan What you have given isn't doing much. It seems all you are doing really is getting a file and starting an intent. Why not just modify the code that works to do what you need? This isn't even my answer I was just reposting it from another question, but it seems easier than starting from scratch